# logical error in Topological sort implementation code

Tags: java, arraylist, vertex, topological-sort

I implemented the topological sort using queue, however, there is a logical error in the Vertex class which prevent this code from working properly.

```
public class TopologicalSort {

public void TopSort(ArrayList<Vertex> vertices) throws CycleFoundException
{   
    int i;      
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
    {   
        for(j = 0; j < vertices.get(i).getAdjacentVertices(vertices.get(i)).size(); j++)
        {
            vertices.get(i).AdjacentVertices.get(j).indegree++;             
        }
    }

    Queue<Vertex> q = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
    int counter = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
    {
        if(vertices.get(i).indegree == 0)
            q.add(vertices.get(i));
    }
    while(!q.isEmpty())
    {
        Vertex v = q.remove();
        v.topNum = counter++;

        for (i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < vertices.get(i).getAdjacentVertices(vertices.get(i)).size(); j++)
            {   System.out.println(vertices.get(i).AdjacentVertices.get(j).indegree);
                if(--(vertices.get(i).AdjacentVertices.get(j).indegree) == 0)
                {
                    q.add(vertices.get(i).AdjacentVertices.get(j));
                    System.out.println(q.toArray()[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(counter != vertices.size())
        throw new CycleFoundException();        
}
```

}

```
public class Vertex {
String name;
int indegree;
ArrayList<Vertex> AdjacentVertices;
public int topNum;

public Vertex(String name, int indegree, ArrayList<Vertex> AdjacentVertices)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.indegree = indegree;
    this.AdjacentVertices =  new ArrayList<Vertex>();   
}

public ArrayList<Vertex> getAdjacentVertices(Vertex a) {

    while (AdjacentVertices.size() != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AdjacentVertices.size(); i++)
        AdjacentVertices.remove(i);
    }

    switch (a.name)
    {
        case "S":
        {
            Vertex A = new Vertex("A", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(A);
            Vertex D = new Vertex("D", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(D);
            Vertex G = new Vertex("G", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(G);            
            break;
        }
        case "A":
        {
            Vertex B = new Vertex("B", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(B);
            Vertex E = new Vertex("E", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(E);            
            break;
        }
        case "B":
        {
            Vertex C = new Vertex("C", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(C);
            break;
        }
        case "C":
        {
            Vertex D = new Vertex("D", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(D);
            break;
        }
        case "D":
        {
            Vertex E = new Vertex("E", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(E);
            break;
        }
        case "E":
        {
            Vertex C = new Vertex("C", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(C);
            Vertex F = new Vertex("F", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(F);
            Vertex I = new Vertex("I", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(I);    
            break;
        }
        case "F":
        {
            Vertex C = new Vertex("C", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(C);
            Vertex T = new Vertex("T", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(T);        
            break;
        }
        case "G":
        {
            Vertex D = new Vertex("D", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(D);
            Vertex E = new Vertex("E", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(E);
            Vertex H = new Vertex("H", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(H);    
            break;
        }
        case "H":
        {
            Vertex E = new Vertex("E", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(E);
            Vertex I = new Vertex("I", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(I);        
            break;
        }
        case "I":
        {
            Vertex F = new Vertex("F", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(F);
            Vertex T = new Vertex("T", 0, AdjacentVertices);
            AdjacentVertices.add(T);        
            break;
        }
        case "T": break;



    }   
    return AdjacentVertices;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

}

in the Vertex class, in getAdjacentVertices method, the first while loop is causing the the list to become empty every time there is a new call to this method, but without this loop the size of the arraylist is multiply by 2 for every call to this function.I can't seem to think of away to modify getAdjacentVertices to work properly. Is there any way to modify the getAdjacentVertices method so that I can remove the while loop and the arraylist doesnt multiply by 2 every call to this method? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you examined what is inside the while loop? Do you notice anything redundant?

Comment: I made the while loop to empty out the arraylist to prevent the arrayList size from multiplying by 2 every call, but this logic is also wrong because it also delete the indegree of adjacent vertices. I haven't really figured out a way to modify the method to work properly.

Comment: First: The while loop is not needed when you have a for loop that iterates over each element in the list, only the for loop is needed. Second: The `ArrayList` class has a method, `clear()`, which "removes all of the elements from the list". Third: Most topoligical sorting implementations use recursion, which I do not see in your code. I would search for a topological sorting algorithm on google and learn from it.

Comment: I think we are talking about 2 different while loops. I don't have any issue with the Sort class, what I am having issue with is the logic in the getAdjacentVertices method. Thank for pointing the clear method out, I forgot about it,but using clear() or while loop would still empty out the arrayList, which would mess up the algorithm because the in-degree of adjacent vertices become all zeroes.